# Does Simultaneous OTG (USB On The Go) + charging depend on OS version?

Tags: android, operating-system, lg, usb-otg

for the past month I was using the following simple configuration to connect my LG G3 both to a webcam and power simultaneously.

[Picture of Phone charging and OTG connection to webcam with a three way cable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKtgC.jpg)

I have updated the OS version from 4.4.2 (Kitkat) to 5.0 (Lollipop). Now my LG G3 will do charging or OTG, but not both simultaneously anymore.

I was wondering if OTG + charging could be affected not only by models of the device but also by the OS version?

Comment: OTG is supported for android version  3.1 Honeycomb and newer. [German source](https://www.droidwiki.de/USB_On-The-Go), I'll do some research for [english source](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36887/how-can-i-determine-if-my-device-has-usb-host-mode-otg-support). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality is purely affected by the kernel bundled with the OS. Lollipop kernels have a lot of changes made, although it might be your carrier blocking the feature. Carriers block a lot of features in this file: `/system/csc/feature.xml`

Your best bet is to find custom LG G3 kernels on XDA and flash one that does the job.

If none of those support OTG+charge, your best bet is to backup your data and flash the Kitkat .kdz for your model, and fix the stagefright issue by adding this to your build.prop file: `media.stagefright.enable-player=false` as mentioned here: [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=62069940&postcount=8)